# Is my Uponor ProPEX supply line plan efficient?

Tags: plumbing

I’m building a house and I’m considering installing the supply lines myself with Uponor ProPEX. My floor plans are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIzn3.jpg.

Making use of Uponor's multi-port tee's, I came up with the following supply line plan here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3L8z.png. Thick lines are 3/4" and thin lines are 1/2".

Am I going down the right path with this plan? What improvements could I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your plan as basically sound and a good design.  One additional thing you may consider.  Many people use softened cold water for toilets, showers, clothes washers, dish washer and sinks except kitchen.  Don't use softened water for drinking, cooking & ice machine for health reasons and not to hose bibs because of volume. The softened water is less hard on your fixtures and they will be easier to keep clean.  Softened water in the shower is a little more pleasant and will extend the life of your soap products.  And as long as you have spent the money for the softener, you may as well reap the full benefits. You will also add apparent value to your house with softened cold water throughout the house.

Comment: I agree with Paul on the soft water. I would use 1" per for main supply lines. ¾" PEX is about the size of ½" copper. Check the flow rates for ¾" and 1" PEX. I think it is well worth the money to upsize to 1" especially with your layout.

Comment: Paul is mostly correct, but if you have a water softener then you soften everything except irrigation/hose bibs like he said. I've never heard of plumbing hard water to a kitchen sink, because the sodium levels are negligible even for people with high blood pressure. Add a reverse osmosis system if you're concerned about your health. If you want to get fancy, add a hot water return line so you can use a hot water recirculating pump so you have nearly instant hot water.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. Good point about the soft water. I uploaded my updated plan here (https://i.imgur.com/AbvA8Kl.png) factoring in the softened cold water. I could do soft or hard cold water to the kitchen sink and ice maker...not sure what is preferred?

Uponor AquaPEX flow rates are listed here: http://bit.ly/2zJXZ2s. 1/2" = 1.1 gpm, 3/4" = 2.2 gpm, and 1" = 3.6 gpm. Does it make sense for me to upsize to 1" main lines knowing these numbers?

Comment: Yes I missed that on the first round.  Definitely use the 1" line for the mains.  Everything works better when you have adequate pressure all around.  So inexpensive now.  Such a pain later.